# httpinteceptor with header values from an observable

Tags: angular

I am trying to append headers to HTTP calls. The headers values will come from an observable. While no error is emitted, the headers are not being added to my requests.

I am totally blank as to why it is not waiting for the observeable.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHeaders
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ConfigService } from "../services/config.service";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class InterceptAPICalls implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    let headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    };

   return new Observable(observer=>{
    this.configService.currentConfig()
        .pipe(map(e => {

                headers['key'] = e["key"];
                headers['X-Allowed-Elapsing'] = e["allowed-elapse"] ;

              const clonedRequest = req.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders(headers)
              });
              return next.handle(clonedRequest);
        }));
   })

  }
}
```

Briefly, currentConfig looks like this.

```
    currentConfig() : Observable<any>{

     return new Observable(observer=>{
        observer.next({'key':'key','allowed-elapse': 9909});
        observer.complete();
     });

       }
```

Comment: What does currentConfig look like? You're also just using a pipe and map and not subscribing to it.

Comment: simply put, it spits out some dictionary data @Mickers. see sample in my updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried this, it works fine in my app.

```
export class InterceptAPICalls implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let headers = req.headers;
    headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    return this.configService.currentConfig()
      .pipe(
        first(),
        switchMap(config => {
          headers = headers.set('key', config['key']);
          headers = headers.set('X-Allowed-Elapsing', config['allowed-elapse']);
          return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
        })
      );
  }
}
```